# on hover, div takes over entire li

Tags: jquery, css, animation, hover

I've got an unordered list, with each li containing an img and a div. My goal is that hovering over the div will make the img do something. For now it's just add/remove class, but that's a placeholder. The add/remove works, but it's not the problem (though if you have tips about that, always happy to get input from anyone more experienced).

The issue is that the hovered-div, upon hovering, suddenly expands to fill the entire li, and also appears to lose its upper padding temporarily. Which means that when that div is replaced with a fancy button... the button will likely jump just as much as the current plain text.

The html:

```
<ul id="headmenu">
    <li id="kite1">
        <img src="img/kitesani1a.png" id="kites1a" />
        <div id="attend" class="headmenulink">attending</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css:

```
ul#headmenu { margin: 2em 0 0 0; padding: 0; }
ul#headmenu li { margin: 0 1% 0 0; padding: 0; width: 19%; float: left; display: inline; list-style: none;}
ul#headmenu img { padding-bottom: 5em; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100; }
li .headmenulink { padding-top: 2em; position: relative; bottom: 0; left: 0; border:1px solid blue; }

ul#headmenu li img {
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.kite1ahover {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
}
```

(In the live versions, the css is more verbose.) Last, the current draft jQuery bits:

```
$("#attend").hover(function(){
    $("#kites1a").addClass('kite1ahover').delay(500).queue(function(next){
        $(this).removeClass('kite1ahover');
        next();
});
```

I did a jsfiddle at but it's giving me strange errors. Not sure if it'll work to edit, but just in case, it's at http://jsfiddle.net/klh02/5UMK5/7/ -- then I also did a stripped-down real-world example, at http://www.karinoyo.com/temp/index.php. If you open the live version (not the fiddle), you'll see the temporary blue border expand on hover, at the same time the text jumps up a line or two. (note: the only 'live' hover is on the 'attending' li, first li from the left.)

Is the expanding div because of the CSS? or is it because of the jQuery? or is this just something that happens in a case like this, and I'll need to do some creative positioning to get the div to stay put instead of expanding/jumping?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `ul`'s before id selectors is unnecessary (and my be wrong), because ids are unique.

Comment: It's not actually wrong per se, it's just redundant (and mostly for my own edification when in draft, which is what I am right now). I clean up when before going live, but even if it stayed in, my understanding is that it wouldn't be a significant issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle the DIV grows because the hover class has a float inside:

```
.kite1ahover {
    float:right; /* remove this */
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(10deg); 
    -o-transform:rotate(10deg);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}​
```

Which breaks the box height. As soon as you remove it, the DIV stops growing. The "strange" error you got came from the missing closing brackets in the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#attend").hover(function(){
        $("#kites1a").addClass('kite1ahover').delay(500).queue(function(next){
            $(this).removeClass('kite1ahover');
            next();
        });
    });
// missing brackets here...
});
```

You'll find a working variant [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/rjT4M/).

Comment: Yep, as I replied above, I get tonight's cookie for stupid error caused by c&p code from another project. Once I realized that and removed the float, everything behaved. Also, ahah on the strange jsfiddle error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The bouncing is because you make the img float with that "kite1ahover" class

When elements float, the size they occupy are ignored (as if they are hollow) and so the div becomes the top element in that box, hence the jumping to the top.

If you stop using float and instead use a combination of left, right, top, bottom, you should be able to move img's as you'd like

e.g.
`position:relative; left:100px;`

Comment: Yeah, I just now realized that. I win for stupid error of the night! Go me. Serves me right for just pulling in some code from another project as an easy insert. You're right, once I took that out, the strange behavior stopped.